# If $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leq e^{Re(z)}$, then $f(z) = \lambda e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that if $f$ is entire and $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leq e^{Re(z)}$ $\forall z \in \Bbb C$, then $f(z) = \lambda e^z$ where $\lambda$ is a constant.

I know $e^{Re(z)} = \lvert e^z \rvert$, so $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leq \lvert e^z \rvert$. I don't think we can use Cauchy's Estimates here since we don't know if $f(z)$ is bounded and $e^z$ is not a constant. Then what else can we do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know if $z=x+iy$, then $e^x=|e^z|$, so that the assumption is equivalent to $|f(z)|\leq|e^z|$. Putting $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{e^z},$$ we see $|g(z)|\leq1$, but it is entire, hence is constant by Liouville's Theorem. This means $f(z)=\lambda e^z$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
|f(z)|\le|e^z|=e^{\Re z}
$$
Now apply Liouville's theorem to the function $\frac{f(z)}{e^z}$ and observe that for some $\lambda\le1$ we have $f(z)=\lambda e^z\square$